# Laravel load very slow for local css and js resources

Tags: javascript, css, performance, laravel-5, assets

I have a problem with my Laravel project:
I noticed that all my local resources are loaded very slowly and are files
really small.
The cdn are much faster.
Could you tell me how fix this?

[image]

Comment: Running with Homestead on Virtualbox? Try changing the network mount driver (to NFS for example) This has helped me a while back.

Comment: to run project i use "php aritsan serve" an go on browser on http://127.0.0.1:8000/. as Db i use phpmyadmin by Laragon.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running on laravel serve on port 8000, make sure zend debug or x-debug is disabled. that causes a lot of delay in loading resources.

Answer (score 0):

if you dev in vs-code after you run command `php artisan serve` in vs-code terminal

jus you close this terminal `CTRL + ~` For me It is several times faster.