# Laravel: local running the application with ASSET_URL set to local port loads forever

Tags: laravel, php-7.2

I am new with Laravel.

The app runs perfectly fine in the production but when running it locally it takes lot of time to load even for a simple login page (something around 15min).

I tried running it with command:

```
php artisan serve
```

and:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public/
```

Tried removing:

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

But nothing helped.  Also tried:

```
php artisan  view:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

But I get an error as lot of routes use closure and changing them is lot of effort.

It loads rapidly when I remove or change url in `.env` for `ASSET_URL`.

Comment: I got the same on XAMPP, on CLI and live server its working fine

Comment: Some possible reasons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51248247/laravel-load-very-slow-for-local-css-and-js-resources, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283574/is-laravel-really-this-slow ...

Comment: @Don'tPanic I saw those and sadly nothing helped. There is some problem with routing or resource loader. But as I am new with PHP I am not able to detect that.